# Netty - How to setup a pipeline to transform Http1 -> Http2

Tags: http, netty, http2

I'm looking for guidance on how to setup a ChannelHandler which can accept an HTTP1 connection but encode the message as HTTP2 and pass it along to a *Http2FrameListener*.

*InboundHttpToHttp2Adapter* seems to be a good example of that, however I'm not sure how to do the Outbound data of transforming the HTTP2 data back to HTTP1.

Comment: Would recommend to look at this example: https://github.com/netty/netty/tree/4.1/example/src/main/java/io/netty/example/http2/helloworld/server

Comment: thanks @Ingrim4 that helped but I'm looking to accept HTTP and then send it to the HTTP2 handler. It's not simple because the abstractions are different in netty between HTTP & HTTP2 (i.e. HTTP2 doesn't use the channel handler concept)